# avoid printing parameter from DoxygenToolkit in vim

Tags: c++, vim, doxygen

I am using the vim plugin `DoxygenToolkit` that is pretty cool.

by highlighting a function and calling `:Dox` it setup a doxygen comment like below.

```
/// @brief 
///
/// @param id
///
/// @return 
int32_t printme(int32_t it)
```

Is there any setting in this tool that prevent to prepare only the @brief section without showing  the `@return` and `@param` ones?

I tried by setting thse 2 parameters, but I cam see that the argument of the function is still printed out together with many lines.

```
let g:DoxygenToolkit_paramTag_pre=""
let g:DoxygenToolkit_returnTag="" 

/// @brief 
///
/// id
///
/// 
int32_t printme(int32_t it)
```

Comment: Why don't you ask the plugin's author? He should know best, and would be most interested in your enhancement request!

Comment: The author doesn't update the project since 2010 so I didn't want to bother. At the end I've looked into it; since it is a very simple plugin/script it is more simple to edit it myself..at least I'll learn more about VIM. Anyway thanks for the note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is not the plugin you are using, but anyway, with [lh-cpp](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhCpp) (`:DOX` command), you would be able to override the [doxygen-function snippet](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/cpp/trunk/after/template/dox/function.template) and keep/remove/change whatever you wish. The plugin takes care of detecting everything that can be detected, the snippet formats them.